# Change spacing between loop cuts

Tags: modeling, loop

What is the best way to achieve loop cuts like this please:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Create loop cut with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, keep them selected, bevel with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>.

Comment: That's clever :)

Comment: Seems rather like a basic, no?   ;)

Comment: Just as I think I'm getting better at this, something so simple trips me up and makes me question my whole life! Thanks @moonboots

Comment: @user122169 Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if it helped :)